# docker compose aspnetcore build vs dotnet run

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, https

Running a dotnetcore app via docker (compose) does not resolve like it does via "dotnet run".

I run it using dotnet build, dotnet run it comes up "listening on https://localhost:44301" and puts it in the Debug folder I reference. From docker the same dir says "listening on https://[::]:44301" but gives a 500 error trying to proceed to the site splash page.

Here is my current Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
COPY mydir/myproj /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:3202,nu1503 -p:RestoreUseSkipNonexistantTargets=false 

RUN dotnet build 
EXPOSE 44301/tcp
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://*:44301

WORKDIR /app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myproj.dll"]
```

That is essentially the file currently to try to debug this issue. Any help "resolving" what the difference is would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, You'll need to replace {APPFOLDER} and {DLLNAME} with your settings :

```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY ./{APPFOLDER} .
    WORKDIR /openssl
    COPY ./somecert.pfx .
    
    WORKDIR /app/{APPFOLDER}/
    RUN dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-x64 -o out /p:publishsinglefile=true /p:publishtrimmed=true
    
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime-deps:3.1 AS runtime
    WORKDIR /openssl
    COPY --from=build /openssl/somecert.pfx ./    
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=build /app/{APPFOLDER}/out ./
    ENTRYPOINT ["./{DLLNAME}"]
```

You can then use this to build it :

```
docker build -f .\Dockerfile C:\Git\WHEREMYAPPIS\ -t somename/myapp:latest
```

And this to run it :

```
docker run -p 5100:80 somename/myapp:latest


WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseKestrel(options =>
    {
        options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000);  // http:localhost:5000
        options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 80);         // http:*:80
        options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 443, listenOptions =>
        {
            listenOptions.UseHttps("certificate.pfx", "password");
        });
    })
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();
```

Comment: I would like to keep it https, but I know that is my problem because I get this same issue only with other https dotnetcore application samples I download. I no longer think it is my dockerfile but something with docker handling https.

Comment: You need to put a https cert in in that case.